# query xml table after inserting soap xml contents

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

Hi after I've inserted my soap xml contents into a table called foo but i'm having issues query the contents.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <ns:AccountQueryPage_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/">
- <ListOfAccount xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Data" lastpage="true">
- <Account>
  <Id>CCC-TEST01</Id> 
  <AccountName>John Smith Pty Ltd</AccountName> 
  </Account>
  </ListOfAccount>
  </ns:AccountQueryPage_Output>
```

my query is

```
select xmltype( xml_response ).extract('//AccountName/text()',
                                        'xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/" ' ||
                                        'xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Data').getStringVal() from Foo
```

and I get

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 2
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

any help as to what im doing wrong?

thank you

@ruudvan

Hi ruudvan I wanted to ask if u knew how to extract the record count from the xml file

ie I want to grab 17680

kind regards

Liem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions060.htm) in 11g. You should instead try to use XMLTABLE and XMLQUERY.

Here is how to retrieve values from your XML. I added another test account to your XML so you know this works on multiple rows.

```
WITH subq AS (SELECT XMLTYPE ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <ns:AccountQueryPage_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/">
 <ListOfAccount xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Data" lastpage="true">
 <Account>
  <Id>CCC-TEST01</Id> 
  <AccountName>John Smith Pty Ltd</AccountName> 
  </Account>
  <Account>
  <Id>CCC-TEST02</Id> 
  <AccountName>Test Pty Ltd</AccountName> 
  </Account>
  </ListOfAccount>
  </ns:AccountQueryPage_Output>') AS my_xml FROM DUAL)
SELECT Acct_id, Acct_Name
  FROM subq,
       XMLTABLE (
          xmlnamespaces ('urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/' AS "ns",
                         DEFAULT 'urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Data'),
          '/ns:AccountQueryPage_Output/ListOfAccount/Account'
          PASSING subq.my_xml
          COLUMNS Acct_ID VARCHAR2 (30) PATH 'Id',
                  Acct_Name VARCHAR2 (30) PATH 'AccountName');
```

Comment: Thanks ruudvan will give it go much appreciated

Comment: hi could I replace the hard coding of xml contents for a select clob column ? eg WITH subq AS (SELECT  XMLTYPE(xml_response) AS my_xml FROM scott.foo) when I try to I get the error ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 2
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: What is the datatype of the field xml_response? You don't need to write that subquery if you already have the xml in a table. Just `SELECT columns FROM SCOTT.foo f , XMLTABLE( ....PASSING f.xml_response COLUMNS ..... );`. Make sure the xmlnamespaces and xpath are the same or change the query accordingly.